# Looking for a Lightweight gallery to replace the stock gallery

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gallery

I am looking for a lightweight gallery with following characteristics:

1. No annoying 2D/3D animations
2. Possibility to set wallpaper
3. Classification by folders
4. Fast or at least faster then standard Cooliris gallery
5. No background services like Just Pictures!

Comment: Umm.. what's wrong with the stock gallery? It does not have fancy animations, you can set wallpapers, have folders, it's fast I think, and I'm not aware of any background services it uses.

Comment: Stock gallery is so slow

Comment: I agree stock gallery (the one you can find under the name "Gallery 3D" on the market) is really slow, unless you don't have a lot of pictures. The UI is great though, it's too bad that performances are poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [QuickPic](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&feature=search_result): it's simple and truly fast :)

Comment: I like it, really fast and not much CPU occupation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Picturen Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.silencecork.photography&feature=search_result).  On first run it can be a bit slow to load but after that everything is fast.  I think the app meets all the points on your list.  It looks like the app is still in development with a full version coming soon with more features.

[Link to developer's site](http://www.silencecork.com/)